# How to Index a Json file into a Solr with multivalued fields

Tags: json, solr

When I'm trying to index my json file into solr I face the following error:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http
://localhost:8983/solr/ontoneo/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":16},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START at [138], fie
ld=http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#intersectionOf",
    "code":400}}
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException
: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/on
toneo/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/ontoneo/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.146
```

The line 138 of my json file is shown as follow:

```
{
  "@id" : "_:genid117",
  "@type" : [ "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class" ],
  "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#intersectionOf" : [ {
    "@list" : [ {
      "@id" : "_:genid121"
    }, {
      "@id" : "_:genid119"
    } ]
  } ]
},
```

I have done some research about it and found that the problem is the field list that is multivalued. Trying to fix it I have added the valued field into the file `managed-schema.xml` from my collection. The line of code is shown bellow:

```
<field name="list" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

But when I run the solr to index, the problem persists. What is going wrong?

Comment: Setting `list` as a multivalued field is the way to go. The field type here is not the issue. However, when changes are maid to the schema, the whole index need to be deleted and recreated. Did you delete Solr index before reindexing ?

Comment: No. There was no document indexed to delete. What I did was to restart the server and try to index again. No success.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you defined the field of type "text_general" but then passing JSON data to index. Did you mean to index "JSON string" instead of JSON object?

Comment: yes, for purposes of search I believe the String is the best option.